# How to fix Attempted import error when building in Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, import, export, netlify

I have a React project that builds fine in my computer, but when I push it into my github repository, Netlify can't build it because of an import error. The thing is, I checked it many times, and it works on my computer, the import is correct. But for some reason I can't build it in Netlify.

Here is the build log:

```
6:11:53 PM: $ react-scripts build
6:11:55 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
6:12:19 PM: Failed to compile.
6:12:19 PM: ./src/views/Player.js
6:12:19 PM: Attempted import error: 'checkForPlayer' is not exported from '../Spotify'.
6:12:19 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my Player.js import

```
import { getState, checkForPlayer, transferPlaybackHere, getHashParams } from '../Spotify'
```

Here is my Spotify.js export

```
function checkForPlayer(authToken, player, setPlayer, playerRef, state, setState) {
    if (window.Spotify !== null) {
        const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
            name: "Reactify",
            getOAuthToken: cb => {
                cb(authToken);
            }
        });
        createEventHandlers(player, state, setState);
        console.log("Conectado");
        player.connect();
        setPlayer(player);
        playerRef.current = player;
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkForPlayer, 1000, authToken);
    }
}
exports.checkForPlayer = checkForPlayer;
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this "bug"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved it by exporting each function with

export function checkForPlayer(authToken, player, setPlayer, playerRef, state, setState) {
....
}

and removing

exports.checkForPlayer = checkForPlayer;

Comment: Have the same problem. You saved me hours. Thanks